# Subscription based access in Wordpress using woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site that besides some other pages, it has 10 pages which I want them to be with limited access. Basically, I want a page to be visible to a person only after he paid a subscription. Subscriptions can be for 1, 3 or 6 months. A person can buy subscriptions for one or more pages(with different periods of time). Each subscription should expire at the required time.

I am planning to sell those subscription using Woocommerce. So far I have tried to use Private Content but I can't get a link between WooCommerce and Private Content. Also, the only payment gateway that I managed to set up so far is PayPal, but I want to use Skrill, Neteller and Credit Cards as well.

1. How can I set up those subscriptions in order to permit access to those private pages?
2. How can I set up the payment options in order to use Skrill, Neteller and CC for the subscriptions?
3. I need to know who subscribed to what page (basically knowing his email that he used to register on the website) so I can send different emails depending on page the person subscribed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi better to use a subscription plugin like

-- wordpress s2membership
-- wishlist membership

These plugins provide the whole functionality you are asking for .
1 you can set membership levels
2 restrict the page content to only paid subscribers
3 and choose the payment gateways also

Comment: For s2membership I think I have to add custom payment gateways and I'm not sure how to do that, for Skrill and Neteller.